# Simplest way to refresh ListBox with custom ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm using ListBox with custom ItemsSource:

```
this.ListOfPersonsListBox.ItemsSource = (List<Person>)ListOfPersons.AllPersons;
```

ListOfPersons is a static class so it cannot implement INotifyPropertyChanged nor IObservableCollection.

What's the simplest way to redraw my ListBox after updating the list? My current code works, but I would like to find a cleaner solution:

```
    private void SyncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListOfPersons.Sync();
        this.ListOfPersonsListBox.ItemsSource = null;
        this.ListOfPersonsListBox.ItemsSource = ListOfPersons.AllPersons;
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify why ListOfPersons needs to be a static class? If it's just for convenient access among multiple pages, consider making it an application-wide property. Then you could use an ObservableCollection as keyboardP mentioned.

Comment: @JoshEarl could you please explain what do you mean by "application-wide property"? I'm a beginner and never heard of such thing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider using an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead of a `List`. It implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` internally. You can loop through your list and add each element to a new `ObservableCollection` object and bind this to the `ListBox`.

If you're going to convert often, you could just create an `Extension method`

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> myList)
{
    var oc = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    foreach (var item in myList)
        oc.Add(item);
    return oc;
}
```

Comment: You can create an `ObservableCollection` straight from a list. `var oc = new ObservableCollection<Person>(ListOfPersons.AllPersons);`

Comment: @ChrisF - There's no overload for `ObservableCollection<T>(List<T>)` in Silverlight on WP7. Might be available in Mango since that runs SL4.

Answer (score 1):

Shaeak,

The `Application` class lives for the duration of the app lifecycle. If you have something that needs to be accessible from multiple pages throughout the app's life, one solution is to create a partial class that inherits from `Application` and create a property on this partial class.

[This article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8c85cf/4383/) has an explanation about two thirds of the way down the page.